# Reading a user specifed column from CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, zip

I've written a small script that scans the content of a csv file for a series of location names, and then uses Geolocation API to fetch and display Latitue and Longitude co-ordinates.

Here, I've assumed that always the **second column** of the csv contains the location name. A variable **realname** corresponds to that column in `para1,realname=zip(*data)` . But now I want to make the program more general and robust, and ask the user to enter a custom column number to read location names from. How can I read data from a **user specified column** from a CSV in python?

```
import csv
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path=raw_input("Enter source filepath: ")
# argnum=int(raw_input("Parameter column No: "))
latlist=list()
lnglist=list()
try:
    with open(path,'r+') as filein:
        data=csv.reader(filein, skipinitialspace = True)
        para1,realname=zip(*data)
    for item in realname:
        urlpath="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+ item + "&sensor=true"
        xml = urllib.urlopen(urlpath)
        tree = ET.parse(xml)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for location in root.iter('location'):
            lat=location.find('lat').text
            latlist.append(lat)
            lng=location.find('lng').text
            lnglist.append(lng)
    filein.close()

    print "\n\nLATS\n==========================\n"
    for lats in latlist:
        print lats
    print "\n\nLONGS\n==========================\n"
    for longs in lnglist:
        print longs

except Exception,e:
        print str(e)
```

Comment: You can read a specified column with `for item in (row[argnum] for row in data):` where `argnum` is a (zero-based) integer column number.

Comment: P.S. You also don't need the `filein.close()` because the `with` statement takes care of closing the file for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a [**generator expression**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions) to extract the desired column from each row of data read from the csv file, and then iterate over that with a[**`for`**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)loop.

A nice thing about this approach is that it could easily be expanded to extract multiple columns from each row if needed. It's also fairly memory efficient because it iteratively processes one row at a time from the file.

```
import csv
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = raw_input("Enter source filepath: ")
col = int(raw_input("Column # to extract (starting with zero): "))
latlist = []
lnglist = []
try:
    with open(path, 'r+') as filein:
        data = csv.reader(filein, skipinitialspace=True)
        for item in (row[col] for row in data):
            urlpath = (
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + 
                item + "&sensor=true")
            xml = urllib.urlopen(urlpath)
            tree = ET.parse(xml)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for location in root.iter('location'):
                lat = location.find('lat').text
                latlist.append(lat)
                lng = location.find('lng').text
                lnglist.append(lng)
    print "\n\nLATS\n==========================\n"
    for lats in latlist:
        print lats
    print "\n\nLONGS\n==========================\n"
    for longs in lnglist:
        print longs
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

P.S. Since your exception handler does nothing but print the exception, it might be better to just leave the`try/except`block out because that's what would happen automatically anyway, plus it would print something very useful called a *traceback* which will show exactly where the problem occurred.

Comment: Thank you martin!
Could you please help me understand how the statement
    for item in (row[argnum] for row in data) work? I'm kinda new to python and put together my code in bits and pieces.

Comment: user3210476: Sure...see updated answer. Please consider also up-voting my answer if you think it's worthy.

Comment: Thanks a ton again! I was too lazy to change the exception handling so I just left it that way :P I'm sorry, but I don't have enough rep yet to upvote ;(